# how to use view from another controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

for globalization reason I need to be able to do this:

```
 http://mysite/home
 http://mysite/Accueil
```

what I tried is to inherits home control in my Accueil class:

```
 Public Class AccueilController
     Inherits HomeController

 End Class
```

problem is, it's trying to go into the Accueil folder and look for index.aspx there

```
The view 'Index' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Accueil/Index.aspx
~/Views/Accueil/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
```

I would want it to use, so I don't have to duplicate code

```
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
```

what would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that for globalization reasons you need to have both urls render the same view. In this case I would suggest you to use the routing engine and map `Accueil` to `home`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "accueil",
    "Accueil/{action}",
    new 
    { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message contains your answer. The view engine performs a progressive search for a matching view that moves through a set of configured folders. If you want a shared index view, put the Index.aspx file in ~/Views/Shared/, and that should do the trick.

If you need more flexible view locations, you could look into implementing a custom ViewLocator.

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/31/37827/

Comment: problem is, everything would be put there if I start doing that, everything from every controller this a big no no

Comment: Why everything from every controller? If you just need a shared Index page, then stick it in shared. All the other views for other actions on your controllers can stay in their normal location.

Answer (score 0):

Check these posts:
http://damieng.com/blog/2008/04/27/localizing-mvc-for-aspnet-views-and-master-pages
http://oddiandeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/11/localization-with-aspnet-mvc.html
http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx